# Update cached templates

Tags: angularjs, caching, angularjs-directive, browser-cache, angular-template

I make use of `templateUrl` and it works great!

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'partials/directives/template.html'
    };
};
```

However... when I make changes to these templates it doesn't update. In development it isn't a big problem cause I konw what is updated and can just clear the cache manually.

But I can't clear the cache of all users. Is there a way to do this? Like using the CACHE-CONTROL metatag or something like that?

Comment: AngularJS templateCache is cleared when you refresh the browser. If you are still getting old template it is due to browser caching the partials. As you said you need to check the cache headers and adjust them

Comment: I'm not sure what to add. Do I add "no cache" to index.html? Or do I add it to each partial? I also noted that the server is sending the ETAG metadata so why isn't the browser (chrome) using it :(?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? If so, please share.

Comment: Yes I did. I went full retard and disabled caching :/ `app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
 };
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see, you have two options -

1. use `$cacheFactory` service to remove the old cache
   After a template has been fetched, Angular caches it in the default $templateCache services

   ```
   // Please note that $cacheFactory creates a default key '$http'

   var cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');

   // The remove() function removes a key-value pair from the cache, 
   // if it’s found. If it’s not found, then it just returns undefined.

   cache.remove(your url);
   ```
2. use file versioning
   rename the file with each change -  i.e. if your first version of the file is template-1.0.1.html, when you  make some code changes rename it to template-1.0.2.html and so on. This way the new file will be downloaded each time you make some changes.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't there a better way? Both your solutions are trying to fix the symptom not the cause. The fix I'm looking for is where the browser knows that the file has been updated and then fetches it anew. Eg. using the meta ETAG.

Comment: There's an another way - store your templates in js files. They are not cached by angular.

Comment: If we are referring to these kind of 'tricks' then I recall an old one where you don't need to change the name of the template file, but you need to change the request. So it would go like `templateUrl: 'tplFile.html?v=20150503`

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution is to disable caching in the `$httpProvider`

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    };
});
```

I wouldn't recommend this. But it works.